# Add entry to <appname> menu using QML

Tags: macos, qt, qml

I have a C++ application that uses Qt/QML for its GUI.
I'd like to add an entry to the menu with the app's name in the OSX menu bar using QML. I already managed to do this in C++ with QMenu, QActions etc. and it works fine. But in this case it would be sufficient and cleaner to do this in QML.

So far all I could find was using [MenuBar](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-menubar.html), [Menu](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-menu.html) and [MenuItem](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-menuitem.html) - but this only adds new menus to the menu bar. Adding to the existing app name menu does not seem to work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This will be doable with the new experimental [`Qt.labs.platform`](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.8/qtlabsplatform-index.html) module available in Qt 5.8 (yet to be released) : [Qt.labs.platform's `MenuBar`](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.8/qml-qt-labs-platform-menubar.html).

Currently Qt 5.8 is only available in Alpha, this means you'd have to compile it yourself from source to use it and it isn't considered stable.

EDIT : As DenverCoder21 mentionned, it seems that this doesn't make it possible to alter the app menu, only add other menus.

Comment: Sounds promising, but from your link I can't deduce that it will be doable. What would it look like in code or what is the part in your linked documentation hinting at this ability?
Additional menus next to the app name menu can already be achieved with the current implementation. But adding entries to the app name menu not.
Would be nice if you could explain a little further.

Comment: Qt 5.8 beta should be out (hopefully) next week.